# Reduce duplicated entries considering more than one column

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a long dataset in which there are duplicated entries whose data I need to merge, e.g. paste values together.

In my case, I have a database of scientific articles: the strongest unique identifiers are the DOI and the article title, but the first may be missing in one of the copies, and the second may have slight phonetic/graphic differences that are easy to spot for humans but not programmatically (e.g. one copy uses β and the other plain beta).

A "match" are two articles that share at least one of the two columns. That is, I need a way to `dplyr::group_by` by the DOI **OR** the article title (usual `group_by` uses an AND logic).

The only solution that comes to my mind is to repeat the aggregation twice, for each column. Not very efficient given the large number of records.

Example:
imagine an input like:

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1, NA, 2, 2),
    Title = c('A', 'A', 'beta', 'β'),
    to.join = 1:4
)
```

After (OR)grouping and summarising:

```
df %>% 
    group_by_OR(ID, Title) %>% # dummy function
    summarise(
        ID = na.omit(ID)[1],
        Title = Title[1],
        joined = paste(to.join, collapse = ', '))
```

I should get something like this:

```
  ID Title  joined
1  1     A    1, 2
2  2  beta    3, 4
```

That is, the data was grouped by the title for the first group and by the id for the second.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid having to group the data twice, but we can do it sequentially, that way we can be as efficient as possible.

```
library(dplyr)
df_aggregated <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(Title) %>% 
    summarise(Title = first(Title),
              to.join = paste0(to.join, collapse=", ")) %>% 
  group_by(Title)  %>%
    arrange(ID) %>% 
    summarise(ID = first(ID),
              to.join = paste0(to.join, collapse=", ")) %>% 
  select(ID, Title, joined=to.join) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Now,

```
df_aggregated
```

is:

> ```
>   ID Title joined
> 1  1     A   1, 2
> 2  2  beta   3, 4
> ```

Comment: Yep, eventually I did something similar (SO prevent me to self answer for a while). I first group_by Title, impute the missing DOI from the present one, then group_by DOI and use only one instance of the Title. Finally I create a new ID which is the DOI if not missing and the Title if missing. Then I summarise() using the new ID for grouping

Comment: You stated "he strongest unique identifiers are the DOI " therefore, in order to be as efficient as possible, we should FIRST aggregate by DOI (or ID in the example) and then by Title, that way we reduce the data as early as possible.

Comment: uhm, the cases of misspelled titles are far less common than the missing DOIs; would it make sense to fix the missing DOIs first?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found a solution, thanks also to @dario.

First I group by Title and impute the missing DOIs if at least one of the copies has one. Then I ungroup and create a new unique ID, using the DOI if present and the Title for those entries whose no copies have it.
Finally I group and summarize by this ID.

This way the computational-heavy summarising step is done only once.

```
    records %>%
            mutate(
                uID = str_to_lower(Title) %>% str_remove_all('[^\\w\\d]+') # Improve matching between slightly different copies
            ) %>%
            group_by(uID) %>%
            mutate(DOI = na.omit(DOI)[1]) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            mutate(
                uID = ifelse(is.na(DOI), uID, DOI)
            ) %>%
            group_by(uID) %>%
            summarise(...) # various stuff here.
```